# Not able to add sortable functionality to droppables in jQuery

Tags: jquery

I am not able to provide the droppable jQuery UI feature, but not able to make the droppable items to become sortable

Kindly check the code and highlight the issue, so that i can get sortable feature for the items that are droppable.

**HTML Code**

```
<div id="item_container">
    <div class="item" id="i1">               
        <label class="title">T-Shirt 1</label>
        <label class="price">$ 20</label>
    </div>
    <div class="item" id="i2">
        <label class="title">T-Shirt 2</label>
        <label class="price">$ 24</label>
    </div>
    <div class="clear"></div>
</div>

<div id="cart_container">
    <div id="cart_toolbar">
        <div id="cart_items" class="back">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**JS CODE**

```
var total_items = 0;
var total_price = 0;
$(document).ready(function() {

$(".item").draggable({
    revert: true
});
$("#cart_items").draggable({
    axis: "x"
});

$("#cart_items").sortable({
    connectWith: "#cart_items"
});
//$(".ro").sortable();
$("#cart_items").droppable({
    accept: ".item",
    activeClass: "drop-active",
    hoverClass: "drop-hover",
    drop: function(event, ui) {
        $("#cart_items").append("<div style='clear:both'><select class='s1'><option value='1'>1</option><option value='2'>2</option></select></div>");

    }
});
```

});

**CSS Styles**

```
 body
    {
        font-family: Arial, "Free Sans";
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
    }
    #main
    {
        background: #0099cc;
        margin-top: 0;
        padding: 2px 0 4px 0;
        text-align: center;
    }
    #main a
    {
        color: #ffffff;
        text-decoration: none;
        font-size: 12px;
        font-weight: bold;
        font-family: Arial;
    }
    #main a:hover
    {
        text-decoration: underline;
    }
    #item_container
    {
        width: 610px;
        margin: 0 auto;
        margin-top: 10px;
        margin-bottom: 10px;
    }
    .item
    {
        background: #fff;
        float: left;
        padding: 5px;
        margin: 5px;
        cursor: move;
        -webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,.5);
        -moz-box-shadow: 0 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,.5);
        box-shadow: 0 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,.5);
        -webkit-border-radius: .5em;
        -moz-border-radius: .5em;
        border-radius: .5em;
        z-index: 5;
    }
    .title, .price
    {
        display: block;
        text-align: center;
        font-size: 14px;
        letter-spacing: -1px;
        font-weight: bold;
        cursor: move;
    }
    .title
    {
        color: #333;
    }
    .price
    {
        color: #0099cc;
        margin-top: 5px;
        -webkit-border-radius: .5em;
        -moz-border-radius: .5em;
        border-radius: .5em;
    }
    .icart, .icart label
    {
        cursor: e-resize;
    }
    .divrm
    {
        text-align: right;
    }
    .remove
    {
        text-decoration: none;
        cursor: pointer;
        font-weight: bold;
        font-size: 20px;
        position: relative;
        top: -7px;
    }
    .remove:hover
    {
        color: #999;
    }
    .clear
    {
        clear: both;
    }
    #cart_container
    {
        margin: 0 auto;
        width: 495px;
    }
    #cart_title span
    {
        border: 8px solid #666;
        border-bottom-width: 0;
        background: #333;
        display: block;
        float: left;
        color: #fff;
        font-size: 11px;
        font-weight: bold;
        padding: 5px 10px;
        -webkit-border-radius: .5em .5em 0 0;
        -moz-border-radius: .5em .5em 0 0;
        border-radius: .5em .5em 0 0;
    }
    #cart_toolbar
    {
        overflow: hidden;
        border: 8px solid #666;
        height: 190px;
        z-index: -2;
        width: 483px;
        -webkit-border-radius: 0 .5em 0 0;
        -moz-border-radius: 0 .5em 0 0;
        border-radius: 0 .5em 0 0;
        background: #ffffff;
    }
    #cart_items
    {
        height: 190px;
        width: 483px;
        position: relative;
        padding: 0 0 0 2px;
        z-index: 0;
        cursor: e-resize;
        border-width: 0 2px;
    }
    .back
    {
        background: #e9e9e9;
    }
    #navigate
    {
        width: 463px;
        margin: 0 auto;
        border: 8px solid #666;
        border-top-width: 0;
        -webkit-border-radius: 0 0 .5em .5em;
        -moz-border-radius: 0 0 .5em .5em;
        border-radius: 0 0 .5em .5em;
        padding: 10px;
        font-size: 14px;
        background: #333;
        font-weight: bold;
    }
    #nav_left
    {
        float: left;
    }
    #nav_left a
    {
        padding: 4px 8px;
        background: #fff;
        -webkit-border-radius: .5em;
        -moz-border-radius: .5em;
        border-radius: .5em;
        text-decoration: none;
        color: #0099cc;
    }
    #nav_left a:hover
    {
        background: #666;
        color: #fff;
    }
    #nav_right
    {
        float: right;
    }
    .sptext
    {
        background: #ffffff;
        padding: 4px 8px;
        margin-left: 8px;
        -webkit-border-radius: .5em;
        -moz-border-radius: .5em;
        border-radius: .5em;
        color: #666;
    }
    .count
    {
        color: #0099cc;
    }
    .drop-active
    {
        background: #ffff99;
    }
    .drop-hover
    {
        background: #ffff66;
    }
```

any tips on gettnig this done is realy helpfull

Comment: Did you mean to make the sortable container itself draggable? I think that's what's causing the issue.

Answer (score 0):

The following code fixed the issue

```
 $("#cart_items").sortable({
       revert: true
  });
```

The Target Div was not declared as a sortable one.